Explore Regedit.exe to the specified address from the CommandLine
Generally, when we want to navigate to one of the registry addresses, we open regedit.exe then copy-paste the address into address bar, then press enter.
For example Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console

I tried doing it via Commandline, without opening regedit.exe directly, it seems to fail:
# CMD
regedit.exe /e /a "HKCU\Console"
# VBS
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "regedit.exe /e HKCU\Console"
# PoweShell
Start "regedit.exe" -ArgumentList "/e, HKCU\Console"

So, how can I do that?
